# Bootstrap slideshow carousel full screen with thumbnails

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I really want to know how to add thumbnails instead of the indicator icons for Bootstraps Carrousel theme.  I have tried many things.  Not too familiar with JS or jQuery but know enough to implement suggestions.  I have tried to use different Bootsnips (ie. http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/article-carousel-with-images-indicators) but no luck.  I want thumbnails and want the chevron icons on the right and left to work as well.

Here's an example of what I'm looking for:

[image]
<sub>(source: [e-junkie.com](https://static.e-junkie.com/sslpic/130809.1ff3e93cd32e47a64de42d9dcf6b06f1.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 examples of carousel's with thumbnail navigation on Bootply..

http://www.bootply.com/KGPbOr2hcH

http://www.bootply.com/pbd9GfSREm